# How to handle localstorage with result of a call to an external API in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

The main gold is to make a serch bar from an external API. I'm using Context API to provide a global state, and a custom async hook to make a call to a pokeapi, I'm currently available, to store the data searched in localstorage, but the thing is that I store that data from a state that changes in a event, so when I reload the page the state is undefined, and sets the local storage value to undefined... there is a better approach to solve this?

context:

```
import React,{createContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import { usePokemonReducer } from './PokemonReducer'
import {FIND_POKEMON} from './Actions'
export const PokemonContext = createContext()

const PokemonProvider = ({children}) => {
    
    const [state, dispatch] = usePokemonReducer(()=>{
        const localData = localStorage.getItem('pokemons');
        return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
    });

    const { pokemon } = state;

    const findPokemon = (pokemon) => dispatch({ type: FIND_POKEMON, pokemon})

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('pokemons', JSON.stringify(pokemon.pokemon));
    }, [pokemon]);

    const providerValues = {
        pokemon,
        findPokemon,
    }

    return (
        <PokemonContext.Provider value={providerValues}>
            {children}
        </PokemonContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default  PokemonProvider;
```

customAsyncHook:

```
import {useEffect, useState, useContext} from 'react'
import { PokemonContext } from '../../Services/Store/PokemonContext'
import {FIND_POKEMON} from '../../Services/Store/Actions'
import axios from 'axios'

const useAsyncHook = (id) => {

    const [result, setResult] = useState();

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState('false');

    const { findPokemon } = useContext(PokemonContext)

     useEffect(() => {

      async function getPokemon() {

        try {

          setLoading('true');

          const response = await axios(
            `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`
          );

          setResult(response.data);

          findPokemon({type:FIND_POKEMON, pokemon:response.data });

        } catch (error) {

          setLoading('null');

          findPokemon({type:FIND_POKEMON, pokemon:null });

        }

      }
  
      if (id !== "") {

        getPokemon();

      }

    }, [id]);
  
    return [result, loading];

  }

  export default useAsyncHook
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with reactjs, but I don't think this is the right time to use localStorage. typically localStorage is used to save data so you don't need to re-query. meaning your page would read from local storage instead of doing a query, but I don't see anything in your code that looks like that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use if condition. if pokemon is undefined, you don't need to set item to localStorage.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (pokemon.pokemon !== undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem('pokemons', JSON.stringify(pokemon.pokemon));
    }
}, [pokemon]);
```